# div height 100 percent

Tags: html, css

```
<img id='imgT' src="...">

<div id="divL"></div>
<div id="divR"></div>
```

css

```
body{
    max-width:1024px;
}
#imgT{
    width:100%;
    border:thin solid blue;
    display:block;
}
#divL{
    width:20%;
    height:100px;  // I need 100%
    background:#008080;
    float:left;
}
#divR{
    width:80%;
    height:100px;  // I need 100%
    background:blue;
    float:left;
}
```

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NPjZe/)

So, how can I make the two divs height 100 percent, i.e. from the bottom of image to the bottom of page.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to set the height of `html` and `body` to 100% too before. *Then* you can set your element height 100%.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#divL, #divR {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NPjZe/3/)

Comment: Interesting. Any explanation as to how/why it works that way? Why aren't `html` and `body` at `100%` by default?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard `html` and `body` don't have any specified default heights, so they fallback to `auto`. One would also have to make all parents of the div to height 100% for this to work. And I'd consider it a CSS trick, because it doesn't work in all browsers (i.e IE <= 8).

Comment: Interesting. But this seems to be 100% of current screen/browser-size. How would one go about making to DIVs have 100% height now matter how long the pages are?

Answer (score 9):

There are a few options you may find useful:

vh (viewport height)
vw (viewport width)
vmin (viewport minimum length)
vmax (viewport maximum length)
Now, let’s have a look at a real example. Imagine you want to create a website with two sections, each one of them with the size of the browser window.

Here’s just a simplified code example of the HTML:

```
<div id="welcome">
   your content on screen 1
</div>

<div id="projects">
   your content on screen 2
</div>
```

and here’s the CSS using vh:

```
div#welcome {
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}

div#projects {
    height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
}
```

You can see more in:

http://stanhub.com/how-to-make-div-element-100-height-of-browser-window-using-css-only/