# One-page responsive website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a website with only one page, that is responsive.
The idea is to scroll down with anchors.

However, I have no idea how can I get all the divs fill the whole screen as intended.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro, Century Gothic;
    background: url('images/bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
}

#intro1 { 
font-family:'Press Start 2P', cursive; 
font-size: 80px; 
display: block; 
text-align: center; 
margin-bottom: auto; 
margin-top: auto; 
top: 50%;  
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute; 
}

#intro2 { //This doesn't work. I've also tried to set top with pixels.
top:100%;
height:600px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
font-size: 80px; 
display: block; 
text-align: center; 
margin-bottom: auto; 
margin-top: auto; 
top: 50%;  
font-family: Source Sans Pro;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#products { //This works fine for some reason.
top: 800px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
background: url('images/circuit.jpg');
font-family: Source Sans Pro;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

How could I have each div to fill the whole screen?
I don't want to use any jQuery plugins, I've browsed 
almost every one of the free ones.

Comment: Put your relevant HTML structure here and try to make test case in jsFiddle.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **VH unit of css**. this is actually unit of total viewport height.
So, `100vh = 100% height of the viewport`.

Here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content1" class="content">
    <a href="#content1">content1</a> | 
    <a href="#content2">content2</a> | 
    <a href="#content3">content3</a> 
</div>
<div id="content2" class="content">
    <a href="#content1">content1</a> | 
    <a href="#content2">content2</a> | 
    <a href="#content3">content3</a> 
</div>
<div id="content3" class="content">
    <a href="#content1">content1</a> | 
    <a href="#content2">content2</a> | 
    <a href="#content3">content3</a> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content{height:100vh}
#content1{background:#EEE}
#content2{background:#CCC}
#content3{background:#AAA}
```

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Vj3dZ/

Reference: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Note: Before using, must check the browser compatibility : http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Comment: Works, but I'm looking for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: then you should do html,body{height:100%} and your .targetDiv{height:100%}

Comment: My first div only contains 1 row of text, so it just crops it to 30px high.

Comment: you must provide the jsfiddle then.

Comment: Here's a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LWut5/ Could we move this to chat for further discussion?

Answer (score 0):

They work if you have set body to 100% and the other main divs too!

Set `body` `height: 100;` instead of `auto`

Then for `#intro1` and `#intro1`: 
Remove all types of positioning like `margin`,`top` etc. and then this would work....

[**basic demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqgma/) (*resize browser and then RUN it to see the div taking whole view-port area*)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set

```
HTML { height: 100%;}
```

[Check this question first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122392/div-height-100-percent)