# 3 divs with height of tallest?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have a template I use to create a responsive website. It uses boxes with percentage widths, floats and clears. One example is [this link.](http://conchitasfolkestone.co.uk/) As you can see, the three boxes are different heights. Setting a height is easy enough, but if the content is too long, the div grows bigger than the rest.

My question is, is there an easy way to have all three divs take their height from the tallest div?

CSS for the boxes and the media query is below.

```
.clear{clear:both;}
.box{float:left; margin:1%; padding:1.5%; background:#6f0100;}
.box p.small{font-size:1.1em; margin-bottom:7px;}
.box img{width:100%; height:auto;}
.row{clear:both;}
.center{text-align:center;}
.box.gallery{}
.box.gallery img{width:30%; height:auto; margin:1%; border:1px solid #000; float:left; max-width:165px;}
.box.wedding img{border:4px solid #888; max-width:120px;}
.boxgallery{width:24.55%; margin:0 0.6% 0 0; padding:0;}
.boxgallery.last{margin:0!important;}
    .boxgallery img{float:left; width:100%; height:auto; clear:both; margin-bottom:2%; transition:opacity 0.3s;}
    .boxgallery img:hover{opacity:0.4;}
.h145{min-height:160px;}

.box10{width:5%;}
.box20{width:15%;}
.box25{width:20%;}
.box30{width:25%;}
.box33{width:28.3%;}
.box40{width:35%;}
.box50{width:45%;}
.box60{width:55%;}
.box70{width:65%;}
.box80{width:75%;} 
.box90{width:85%;}
.box100{width:95%;}

@media (max-width: 40em) {
  .box{clear:both; margin:15px auto; width:90%; float:none}
  .h145{min-height:0px!important;}
}

.slicknav_menu{display:none;}
@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
.js #menunav{display:none;}
.js .slicknav_menu{display:block;}

    p.top{display:none;}
div#logo img {float:none; margin:0 auto;}
div#logo{text-align:Center;}
    }
@media (max-width: 700px) {
div#footerleft {float:left; margin: 0 94px 0 0; width: 95%}
    div#footerleft p {float:left; margin-top:0; font-size:16px; color:#fff;}
    div#footerleft p a {color: #bdaec6}
    div#footerright {width: 95%; margin:0; float:left; clear:both;}
    div#footerright img {margin-top:5px}
    div#footerright p {margin-top: 5px; font-size:16px; text-align:left; color:#fff;}
    div#footercontainer{padding:15px;}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try the DIV height 100% solution.
such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122392/div-height-100-percent

Comment: Here's another similar solution on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594891/make-children-divs-the-height-of-tallest-child

Comment: http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc is showing an example about your question. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J9Vac/)** Try like this to get equa height columns

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    display:table;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.row div {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a jQuery solution you could do something like this:

```
var row=$('.row');
$.each(row, function() {
    var maxh=0;
    $.each($(this).find('.box'), function() {
        if($(this).height() > maxh)
            maxh=$(this).height();
    });
    $.each($(this).find('.box'), function() {
        $(this).height(maxh);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If ancient browser support is not an issue, you can create equal height columns using pure css by making use of [css3 flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

for example

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum ... nisl.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
display:flex;
}
.bar {
width:33.3%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwu4u/)

more about flexboxes@ [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

As per posted CSS Code here just update the below lines in your CSS Code.  Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zagezoda/1/edit)**.

> **Note:** You need to update these lines only.

```
.row{display:table; border-spacing: 20px;}
.box {background:#6f0100; margin: 1%;padding: 1.5%; display:table-cell;}
```

Comment: @user3364292 Is this relevant code helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

add the following css

```
#allcontent .row {
    display: flex;
}
.box.box33 {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use flexbox property.

[SAMPLE](http://codepen.io/qtgye/pen/tnfsD)

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 10px; 
}
```